# Relation between VC-dimension and pseudeo-dimension

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, machine-learning

I am thinking about the relation between the VC-dimension and the pseudo-dimension, and confused about them.

Let $H$ be a family of real-valued functions. We can define a function $c(h,t):x\rightarrow 1_{h(x)>t}$ for $h\in H$ and $t\ge 0$.
Based on $c(h,t)$, we define another family of functions $C$ as follows,
\begin{align}
C=\{c(h,t) :h\in H, t\ge 0 \}.
\end{align}

Is VC dimension of $C$ is equal to the pseudo dimension of $H$? How can we prove this?